# PostgreSQL Absolute Ranking

Tags: sql, postgresql

The `users` table is like this:

| Id | Name | Room | Point |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | C | 2 | 30 |
| 4 | D | 2 | 40 |

I want to get ranking with some conditions.
The query is `SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY users.point ASC) rnk FROM users WHERE users.room = 2`
Then the ranking column(`rnk`) is not a absolute ranking.
The query result is

| Id | Name | Room | Point | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | C | 2 | 30 | 1 |
| 4 | D | 2 | 40 | 2 |

But I want absolute ranking, and the expected result is

| Id | Name | Room | Point | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | C | 2 | 30 | 3 |
| 4 | D | 2 | 40 | 4 |

Comment: Even with  the answer by @TheImpaler you still may not have a *absolute ranking*. What results you  want had the points for id 2 had been 30. IE:  | 2 | B | 1 | 30 |. It may be the difference between [rank](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-rank-function/) and  [dense rank](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-dense_rank-function/).

Comment: @Belayer You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rank first, filter later. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select *, rank() over(order by point) as rnk
  from users
) x
where room = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The users are 1 million, then the inner query will rank for all the 1 million users, and next select the users. right? I think there will be performance degradation. How about you? Do I cache the ranking in redis or something? I want to learn the best practice for this case. Thank you for further help.

Comment: @devcrazy "...the inner query will rank for all the 1 million users, and next select the users. right?" -- not necessarily. Since PostgreSQL 12 the optimizer can pierce subqueries. This means it can get the subset of rows with a minimal number of reads. The best way to find out is to get the execution plan for the query.